# Python : get child process pid and add to dictionary with parent process id

Tags: python, pid

My application creates a pid file with details of parent pid in it. I have got a task to need to identify all the child pids associated with parent pid and store in dictionary format to a log.

I have written below script, in that i am able to get the parent pid with file name in dictionary. But stuck in a place in getting the the details of child pid in the output.

**Python version : 2.6**

**To get the child process id used below function**

```
def child(pid):
        process = subprocess.Popen(['pgrep','-P', str(pid) ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True)
        output = process.communicate()
        return output
```

**Child returns output in format**

```
('12345','45678', None)
```

But unsure how to add the returned values to the existing dictionary.

***Sample input file***

```
cat file 1 
39007

cat file 2 
39023
```

***Tried Script***

```
def child(pid):
        process = subprocess.Popen(['pgrep','-P', str(pid) ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True)
        output = process.communicate()
        return output


def get_pids(market):
        files=["file1", "file2" ]
        pids={}
        for pid_file in files:
                try:
                        with open(pid_file, 'r') as f:
                                al_pid = f.readline().strip()
                                child(pid)
                                pids[pid_file]=al_pid
                        f.close()
                except:
                        print("Unable to open : " + pid_file + ". Skipping file")

print pids
```

***recieved Output***

```
{'file': '39007','file2': '39023'}
```

***Expected output***

```
{'file': [39007, child_pid1, child_pid2],'file2': [39023, child_pid3, child_pid4]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can resolve my problem with the below code.

```
files=['file','file2']
pids={}

def child(pid):
        process = subprocess.Popen(['pgrep','-P', str(pid) ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        output = process.stdout.readlines()
        out=[p.strip() for p in output]
        return out


for pid_file in files:
                with open(pid_file, 'r') as f:
                        al_pid = f.readline().strip()
                        pid=child(al_pid)
                        pid.insert(0,al_pid)
                        pids[pid_file]=pid
                f.close()
print pids
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `process_iter` in `psutil` and play with it a little:

```
from psutil import process_iter

for proc in process_iter():
    print(proc)
```

```
import psutil
processID = 11111
current_process = psutil.Process(processID)
print(current_process)
children = current_process.children(recursive=True)
print(children)
for child in children:
    print("Child pid is {}".format(child.pid))
```

Comment: Sorry, server doesnt have psutil module.